# left join table on string like '%table.name%'

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, left-join, sql-like

I am trying to left join products.table and manufacturer.table to implement the manufacturer into the products table

The only problem there is no id linking the tables, so I am trying something like this.

```
 SELECT [kArtikel]
  ,[cArtNr]
  ,a.[cName]
  ,a.[cBeschreibung]
  ,H.cName
  ,[cKurzBeschreibung]
  ,[cHersteller]
  ,[cHAN]
  FROM [db].[dbo].[tartikel] a
  left join [db].[dbo].[tHersteller] h on a.cName Like '%H.Cname%'
  where cHersteller is null
```

But with this query I am recieving only H.cName = Null
After 2 min execute with the same number of products, having cHersteller = Null

While searching I only find examples where join is on some id with where clause. But this is not the possible here.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2014 Express

Comment: Why do you only bother applying the `a` and `h` aliases to some of the columns? Is it a guessing game where the other columns come from?

Comment: because cName and cBeschreibung are present in table H the others not, so it is not realy necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying whether `a.cName` contains the **literal** `H.Cname`, which is probably not what you were gunning for. If you want to have  wildcards around `H.Cname`, you can use the `+` operator:

```
SELECT [kArtikel]
  ,[cArtNr]
  ,a.[cName]
  ,a.[cBeschreibung]
  ,H.cName
  ,[cKurzBeschreibung]
  ,[cHersteller]
  ,[cHAN]
FROM [db].[dbo].[tartikel] a
LEFT JOIN [db].[dbo].[tHersteller] h ON a.cName LIKE '%' + H.Cname + '%'
WHERE cHersteller IS NULL
```

Comment: oh, sure. The answere is obviosly embarrassing. It´s working, thanks